# How do I set one event handler for two elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, event-handling

At the moment the second element is only ever changed after the first one is.

Is it possible to use the same event handler on both elements if they're both drop down box's and keeping both elements selected while constructing the right URL no matter which element receives the event??

```
$(function(){
   var url = '';
    $('#search_region').change(function () {
        url = $(this).val();
        window.location.hash = url;
         console.log(window.location.hash);
    });

    $('#search_categories').change(function () {
       if(url !==''){
         window.location.hash = url+"&"+$(this).val();
       }
        console.log(window.location.hash);
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes, it is.  Have you tried anything? If so, show us.  `$('#search_region, #search_categories').on('change', function() {.... do stuff...;});`

Comment: Hey i'm not sure how to do this with this code that's the reason for the question @cale_b

Answer (score 4):

> At the moment the second element is only ever changed after the first
>   one is.

In that case you can **append the hash value** of *category* to *region*

```
$('#search_region, #search_categories').change(function () {
   var regURL =  $('#search_region').val();    
   var catURL =  $('#search_categories').val();    

   window.location.hash += regURL + ( catURL ? ("&" + catURL) : "" );
   console.log(window.location.hash);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {

  const changeHash = () => if ($('#search_region').val())
    window.location.hash = 
        $('#search_region').val() + "&" + $('#search_categories').val();

  $('#search_region').change(changeHash);
  $('#search_categories').change(changeHash);

});
```

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution to me

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I disagree. I've essentially re-arranged the code in the question. I don't feel that it would be in any way helpful to add "use the same function for both event handlers" in the answer.

Comment: agreed @Iwrestledabearonce.

Comment: It has become my pet peeve to see answers in ES6 with no explanation / disclaimer when the OP _clearly is not using ES6_.  For those who are unfamiliar with ES6 this looks like Greek.  Further, code-only answers are not as useful.  It would be great if you would add some comments / explanation.  OP wouldn't be here if they wouldn't appreciate some instruction.

Comment: @cale_b - in most cases i would agree with you but i feel this is the exception (and op agrees with me). if you can suggest something worth adding that would improve the answer i'd be happy to add it, but i don't feel like linking to the mdn page for arrow functions is much of an improvement, do you? what *exactly* do you think i should explain here?

Comment: Thanks for the friendly response.  Nice to dialog: It's your answer to do what you want with, my only additional input might be that while OP agrees, you should consider that you've posted an answer that will serve many many visitors in the future.  Not all of them will be on the same page / level as OP, and so some description / disclaimer helps those visitors.  I always think of the answer as being _more_ for future visitors than for OP myself...

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){

    $('#search_region, #search_categories').change(function () {

         ...Your logic

    });

});
```

for more info:
https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.